# Having two objects in shopping at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two objects at the same time not one add to my shopping cart. Here is the `controller` and `models` :

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :find_or_create_cart, :only => [:add_to_cart, :show_cart]
  def  list
    @products = Product.sorted.paginate(:per_page => 5 , :page => params[:page])
  end
  def add_to_cart 
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @cart.add_product(product)
    redirect_to(:action => 'show_cart')
  end 
  def show_cart 
  end 

  private 
  def find_or_create_cart
    @cart=session[:cart]||=Cart.new
  end 

end
```

AND the `model` :

```
class Cart 
    attr_reader :items
    attr_reader :total_price

def initialize 
    @items = []
    @total_price = 0.0
end 

    def add_product(product)
    @items << LineItem.new_based_on(product)
    @total_price += product.price
end 


end
```

`Model` which come from a join table :

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product
def self.new_based_on(product)
    line_item = self.new 
    line_item.product = product 
    line_item.quantity = 1
    line_item.price = product.price
    return line_item 
end 

end
```

It is a small application which is supposed to do online shopping, but when I hit the button `add to cart` this will add two objects (same object) to my shopping cart. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you show us the logs? I think your code is really inefficient & I'll post up some cart code we use for you when I get into the office

Comment: It is an old tutorial. Not my code.

Comment: Lol okay, don't worry!

Comment: :). logs is too big to be added here. but briefly it is:

Comment: rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/ostad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/ostad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/ostad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Comment: Rendered /home/ostad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/ostad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (74.6ms)

Comment: Will need more - it doesn't show the error. Can' you just copy and paste the rquest log?

Comment: It was working properly, but then ...adding two objects to shopping cart .. thanks

Comment: Rendered /home/ostad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.7ms)
  Rendered /home/ostad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (110.3ms)

Comment: It is the rest and the whole

Comment: Oscar, it will be best for you to post the log in your question - it gives people the chance to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

**I'll write another answer to address your code, but I felt this might help you.**

We've developed our own cart system for one of our apps (you can see at http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk) we developed based on [Ryan Bates' session models Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/119-session-based-model)

---

**How It Works**

When using sessions to store cart values, you're basically storing a session var with id's from added cart items. Because you want to keep the session as thin as possible, you'll literally just have an array constructed of product id's:

```
session[:cart][:products] = [] # -> to init
session[:cart][:products] << product.id # -> builds array like [1,5,6,1,6,4,1,5]
```

This will allow you to then process the cart as you desire (by reading / manipulating the `session[:cart][:products]` array). If you test the app I referenced, it should help you see it in action

I mentioned your code is inefficient because you're relying on 3 data sources: `LineItem`, `Cart` and `PublicController`. What you really need is `CartController` and `CartSession` for a session-based model. This will allow you to call `LineItem` from your `CartController`, making it lean

---

**Code**

Our session based cart works like this:

```
#app/models/cart_session.rb
class CartSession

#Initalize Cart Session
def initialize(session)
    @session = session
    @session[:cart] ||= {}
end

#Cart Count
def cart_count
    if (@session[:cart][:products] && @session[:cart][:products] != {})
        @session[:cart][:products].count
    else
        0
    end
end

#Cart Contents
def cart_contents
    products = @session[:cart][:products]

    if (products && products != {})

        #Determine Quantities
        quantities = Hash[products.uniq.map {|i| [i, products.count(i)]}]

        #Get products from DB
        products_array = Product.find(products.uniq)

        #Create Qty Array
        products_new = {}
        products_array.each{
            |a| products_new[a] = {"qty" => quantities[a.id.to_s]}
        }

        #Output appended
        return products_new

    end

end

#Qty & Price Count
def subtotal
    products = cart_contents

    #Get subtotal of the cart items
    subtotal = 0
    unless products.blank?
        products.each do |a|
            subtotal += (a[0]["price"].to_f * a[1]["qty"].to_f)
        end
    end

    return subtotal

end

end


#app/controllers/cart_controller.rb
class CartController < ApplicationController
include ApplicationHelper

#Index
def index
    @items = cart_session.cart_contents
    @shipping = Shipping.all
end

#Add
def add
    session[:cart] ||={}
    products = session[:cart][:products]

    #If exists, add new, else create new variable
    if (products && products != {})
        session[:cart][:products] << params[:id]
    else
        session[:cart][:products] = Array(params[:id])
    end

    #Handle the request
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
        format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
    end
end

#Delete
def delete
    session[:cart] ||={}
    products = session[:cart][:products]
    id = params[:id]
    all = params[:all]

    #Is ID present?
    unless id.blank?
        unless all.blank?
            products.delete(params['id'])
        else
            products.delete_at(products.index(id) || products.length)
        end
    else
        products.delete
    end

    #Handle the request
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
        format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
    end
end

 end

#config/routes.rb
get 'cart' => 'cart#index', :as => 'cart_index'
post 'cart/add/:id' => 'cart#add', :as => 'cart_add'
delete 'cart/remove(/:id(/:all))' => 'cart#delete', :as => 'cart_delete'
```

This basically allows you to keep a list of people's cart items in a simple session array. The array then gives you the ability to determine the quantity, product type, brand etc, all from the array. It's the most efficient way, and is what I'd recommend for your app

Comment: Thank you so much . I try to figure it out.

Comment: No problem - you can copy our code if you want. Just change it to suit

Comment: @RichPeck What if one of your colleagues finds it? :P

Comment: I wrote it so it's okay. And plus, code changes at the speed of light - next time we use it, we'll overhaul completely. Might as well share it whilst we've got it

Comment: And plus, our company encourages us to share everything we can. Theory being if you put out your best code publicly, you'll have to try harder to make it even better next time

Answer (score 0):

To address your question directly, I believe you need to do the following:

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :cart, only: :index do
   post :add # -> allows you to add an item
end
```

---

**Views**

```
#app/views/cart/index.html.erb
<% for product in @products do %>
     <%= product.name %>
     <%= product.price %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Controller**

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js
  before_action :cart_init, :only => [:add, :index]

  #index should replace show_cart
  def index
    unless @cart.nil?
        @products = Product.find @cart #-> will allow you to find multiple ID's
    end
    respond_with @products
  end

  #KISS (Keep It Simple)
  def add 
    @cart << params[:id]
    respond_with @cart
  end

  private 
  def cart_init
    @cart = session[:cart][:products] ||= Cart.new #-> keep products in its own key. Allows you to add [:cart][:shipping] etc
  end 

end
```

---

**Model**

```
class Cart 
    attr_reader :items
    attr_reader :total

    def initialize 
        @items = session[:cart][:products] ||= []
        @total = 0.0
     end 
end
```

Comment: @Peck , I got an error : undefined method `[]' for #<Cart:0x0000000475bd78> ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, private 
  def cart_init
    @cart = session[:cart][:products] ||= Cart.new #-> keep products in its own key. Allows you to add [:cart][:shipping] etc
  end 

end

Comment: @Peck , in my code the method got called twice, but when I removed =// require turbolinks from application.js . it works fine. Thanks again for help.